# Nginx replace REMOTE_ADDR with X-Forwarded-For

Tags: php, nginx

I am quite new to Nginx, and it seems all so confusing. I have my server setup perfectly, but the problem is, since my server is protected using a HTTP proxy; instead of logging the real users IP's, it's logging the proxy server IP.

What I tried doing was setting `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` to `$_SERVER['X-Forwarded-For'];` but I'm getting a undefined index error, so I'm guessing I have to define `X-Forwarded-For` in Nginx? But I am not aware how to do so, I have a simple setup, it's just Nginx with PHP. Nothing more, nothing less.

I've searched all over the web, but can't actually find some information that is friendly to understand.

I have access to the source code, if that somewhat helps. I've tried many solutions, but to no avail.

Answer (score 39):

The correct way of doing this is by setting the `real_ip_header` configuration in nginx.

Example with trusted HTTP proxy IP:

```
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1/32;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

This way, the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will be correctly filled up in PHP fastcgi.

[Documentation link - nginx.org](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)

Comment: I have been looking EVERYWHERE for a solution that actually works.  Thank you so much!!!! AWESOME!  Just put it in your..
     server {
          location ~ \.php$ {

block section. and it all works!!!! GREAT JOB!

Comment: use `0.0.0.0/0` and `::/0` to match all ip addresses

Comment: @pravdomil that is a very bad idea and defeats the purpose of this (much needed) security measure). Please don't advise others when you have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 8):

`$http_x_forwared_for` might contain multiple ip addresses, where the first one should be the client ip. `REMOTE_ADDR` should only be the client ip.

So by using regex in your `nginx.conf`, you can set `REMOTE_ADDR` to the first ip of `$http_x_forwarded_for` like so:

```
  set $realip $remote_addr;
  if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ "^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)") {
    set $realip $1;
  }
  fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $realip;
```

Comment: Since it is not possible to use `set` directive in `http` block, It might be better  to use `map` instead.

Comment: This does not work as is, and doesn't support IPv6 addresses!

Comment: @LassePoulsen yes, this regex only works for ipv4, but I'm sure modifying it for ipv6 would be possible. What else is not working "as is"?

Comment: Just in case, there's an official Nginx module `ngx_http_realip_module` with `set_real_ip_from` and `real_ip_recursive` directives for exactly this purpose as mentioned by `@Razvan Grigore` in this SE question answers. Related: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

Answer (score 7):

An addition to @fredrik's answer.
It might be better to set `$real_ip` using `map` directive:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $real_ip {
        ~^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) $1;
        default $remote_addr;
    }
```

Then, set `fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR` in `fastcgi_params` file or a location block:

```
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR          $real_ip;
```

edit: Typo fixed in variable name

Answer (score -1):

I solved my own problem, since PHP gets filtered through FastCGI, I simply added a fast CGI param which set `REMOTE_ADDR` to the variable `http_x_forwarded_for`, so something similar to this:

```
fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: That's one way, but how do you handle cases where requests come in not via proxy, such as test requests from `localhost`?

Comment: Don't do this. This will fail if original client sends X-Forwarded-For header (proxies do this), because then your REMOTE_ADDR will have 2 coma-separated IPs.

Comment: Its good for my case as im getting real ip from different header (cloudflare client ip)