# Debian Server Pb Remote_Addr wrong with apache2 / nginx

Tags: php, nginx, debian, apache2, geoip

First please excuse me for my bad english because I'm a french man...

I have a problem with my debian server.

I recently installed Nginx for get files static such as (css, js, img).

But when i execute $_SERVER var_dump on a php file my remote_addr are wrong. I have now 127.0.0.1.

Files Details for understand situation :

**FILE : /etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**FILE : /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    # Configuration Globale du serveur
    ServerAdmin webmaster@X.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerSignature Off

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**FILE : /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {

    listen 80;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name 78.198.62.X;

    # Header cache control
    add_header  Cache-Control public;

    # Redirection des fichiers statiques
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|swf|mp3|mp4|svg|eot|ttf|woff|txt|xml|json|pdf|zip|doc|ppt|xls)$ {

        expires          max;
            access_log       off;
            error_log        off;
            log_not_found    off;
    }

    # Redirection par défaut
    location / {

        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect          off;

        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   90;
        proxy_send_timeout      90;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
        proxy_buffers           32 4k;

        # Désactivation des logs
        access_log off;
        error_log off;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT $_SERVER PHP:**

```
array (size=35)
  'HTTP_HOST' => string '78.198.62.X' (length=13)
  'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' => string '192.168.0.254' (length=13)
  'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' => string '192.168.0.254' (length=13)
  'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'HTTP_CONNECTION' => string 'close' (length=5)
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0' (length=77)
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => string 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' (length=63)
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => string 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' (length=35)
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => string 'gzip, deflate' (length=13)
  'HTTP_COOKIE' => string '_pk_id.8.3298=7f53d6e0a0332698.1495531633.1.1495532306.1495531633.; FREEBOXOS="paFjdSexOLSr0RgOVjoSeZKdsh2TdXufsoLX475Z9M2SOBuqyc74XVLTzH12kfAB"' (length=144)
  'HTTP_DNT' => string '1' (length=1)
  'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => string '1' (length=1)
  'PATH' => string '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin' (length=60)
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => string '' (length=0)
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => string 'Apache' (length=6)
  'SERVER_NAME' => string '78.198.62.X' (length=13)
  'SERVER_ADDR' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'SERVER_PORT' => string '8080' (length=4)
  'REMOTE_ADDR' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string '/var/www/' (length=9)
  'REQUEST_SCHEME' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => string '' (length=0)
  'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string '/var/www/' (length=9)
  'SERVER_ADMIN' => string 'webmaster@X.com' (length=25)
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => string '/var/www/test_geoip.php' (length=23)
  'REMOTE_PORT' => string '54432' (length=5)
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => string 'CGI/1.1' (length=7)
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => string 'HTTP/1.0' (length=8)
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'GET' (length=3)
  'QUERY_STRING' => string '' (length=0)
  'REQUEST_URI' => string '/test_geoip.php' (length=15)
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/test_geoip.php' (length=15)
  'PHP_SELF' => string '/test_geoip.php' (length=15)
  'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => float 1495606898.941
  'REQUEST_TIME' => int 1495606898
```

**SERVER INFORMATION :**

```
DEBIAN 8.8
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
nginx/1.6.2
PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2017 08:50:21)
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.55
Kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64
```

Comment: Your English is actually great.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you may  have to do little coding to get the real client ip (real_ip_header) or set the real_ip_header in the configuration file.
Take a look at:
http://blog.stevesmind.net/2012/10/nginx-not-reading-real-client-ip-address/

Edit your nginx.conf located on /etc/nginx/ and add the following line:

proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;

[Nginx replace REMOTE_ADDR with X-Forwarded-For](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929599/nginx-replace-remote-addr-with-x-forwarded-for)

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks you very much.
It's worked on http://78.198.62.X/test.php but not worked on my vhost example.com
It's strange

I have configured my vhost apache example.com.

**FILE : /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com**

```
# HTTP SERVER 80
server {

    # Listen Port
    listen 80;

    # Root Directory
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://example.com/
    server_name example.com;

    # Header cache control
    add_header  Cache-Control public;

    # Redirection par défaut
    location / {

        proxy_pass              http://example.com:8080;
        proxy_redirect          off;

        proxy_set_header        Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   90;
        proxy_send_timeout      90;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
        proxy_buffers           32 4k;

        # Désactivation des logs
        access_log off;
        error_log off;
    }
}

# HTTPS SERVER 443
server {

    # Listen Port
    listen 443 ssl;

    # Root Directory
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php;

    # Make site accessible from https://example.com/
    server_name example.com;

    # Certificates Path
    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    # Header cache control
    add_header  Cache-Control public;

    # Redirection par défaut
    location / {

        proxy_pass              https://example.com:8181;
        proxy_redirect          off;

        proxy_set_header        Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   90;
        proxy_send_timeout      90;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
        proxy_buffers           32 4k;

        # Désactivation des logs
        access_log off;
        error_log off;
    }
}
```

**FILE: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:8181>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        <Directory /var/www/example.com>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from all
            AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd
            AuthName "AUTHENTIFICATION"
            AuthType Basic
            <Limit GET POST>
                Require valid-user
            </Limit>
        </Directory>

        ServerSignature Off 
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```