# What is inside $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], if nginx fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR is not set?

Tags: php, nginx

What is inside php's $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], if nginx fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR is not set at all?
I have different behavior of two servers, using nginx and php-fpm. The configurations of both is completely the same. But one returns $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] with new ip value all the time, and another nothing, as expected with no REMOTE_ADDR directive inside fastcgi_param.conf file of nginx.
I include no other configs, but have only

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
```

That's all. But php's $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] has all the time new value.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what  you're asking, but `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is usually the address of the server/system/computer making the request, not your web server.

Comment: See if this is of some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929599/nginx-replace-remote-addr-with-x-forwarded-for

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: the fastcgi_param.conf file was not empty, there was REMOTE_ADDR directive. And the reason was in php code, not in nginx.

P.S. Bad idea to be newbye in Unix. Remember if you're not in sudo and you use vim, you see any root owned file as empty.